# Loop until last worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to apply a format to every worksheet in my current workbook.  I have tried "For Each" and I have tried to Loop through until I reach last worksheet but both error due to different reasons.  Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Method 1: It works on the 1st worksheet but not on the remaining worksheets.

```
Sub format_worksheets()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In Worksheets

        Columns("A:A").Select

           Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
                TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
                Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, Space:=False,     
                Other:=True,TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

        Range("A1").Select

    Next ws


End Sub
```

Method 2:  It doesn't recognise the last worksheet.

```
Sub format_worksheets()

    Dim ws As Worksheet

    ws = Worksheet.Active

    Do

        code

    Loop Until ws = Sheets(Sheets.Count).Active

End Sub
```

Answer (score 4):

In method one, try changing:

```
Columns("A:A").Select
```

To

```
ws.Activate
ws.Columns("A:A").Select
```

... to activate the worksheet and specify the worksheet you want to work with.

Comment: That worked - thank you very much.  I can't believe it was that simple.  Appreciate your input.

Comment: Thanks again - appreciate the help.

Comment: You should mark the question as solved by clicking the green tick.  This prevents other developers (like my self) opening your questions thinking you still need help.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to figure out what you were trying to do with method 2, and I could not. But just because, here's a working version that does not use for each.

```
Sub format_worksheets()
    dim x as Integer
    For x = 1 To Sheets.Count
        Sheets(x).Columns("A:A").TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
                    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
                    Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, Space:=False, Other:=True, TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
    Next x
End Sub
```

Note that this will error if any sheet has no data in Column A. I also left out the select statements because it's best practice to avoid them if they are not necessary.